# Задать масштаб карты по размеру круга, метод circle, google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

По определенному событию я рисую объект circle на карте, радиус и центр вводит пользователь.

```
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: center,
      radius: radius
    });
```

Нужно чтоб по этому событию устанавливались центр карты на центр круга и масштаб карты, наибольший при котором весь круг влазит на экран.  Ну с центром то всё понятно `map.setCenter(center);`, а вот с масштабом не могу додуматься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const bound = circle.getBounds();
map.fitBounds( bound );
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отлично, всё тоже оказывается просто, то, что `map.fitBounds` нужно использовать понимал, но не знал как получить bounds круга